# I invented formulation. provisional patent application filed. if my ex-employee stolen it and misused, what I can do?

Tags: patent-applications, provisional-application

I invented formulation. provisional patent application filed. if my ex-employee stolen it and misused, what I can do to save from infringement.

Answer (score 1):

Given you filed the provisional application then you can follow that up with a non-provisional within 12 months. Hopefully this gets granted and you can then sue the ex-employee. In any case the particulars matter so you would be well advised to discuss this with your patent lawyer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to your future patent protection, an employee ordinarily has duties to their employer that their actions may have breached so you may have more immediate remedies than waiting a few years for a patent to be issued.